# Code Review and Stack Overflow overlap

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, code-review-se, overlap

There are many questions on overlap between several StackExchange sites. Code Review is pretty new, and still in beta, which probably explains why I could not find the question I'd like to ask (and maybe it is too early to ask?):

Is the distinction between Code Review (CR) and Stack Overflow (SO) clear enough? What are the experiences so far?

I ask because when I have a programming related question I find myself looking for solutions in two sites now, where SO used to be *the* place to look (and nearly always find). So, in my experience, life has not become easier. And I find people asking the same question both at SO and CR. Anyone interested has to check two locations then.

The FAQs on what to ask on both sites are clear on where questions on tools and higher lever architecture, but:

Stack Overflow's faq on what to ask says:

> question generally covers: a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, ...

Code Review's faq has:

> ...is for sharing code from projects you are working on for peer review. If you are looking for specific feedback about Code correctness, Best practices and design pattern usage in your code...

I think this often makes people wonder where to go with their question. Now I don't know if SO's faq is going to be changed when CR is officially released? Or will the distinction gradually become clear as time goes by?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't see the problem here:

- Stack Overflow: You've an actual question about coding.
- Programmers: You've a conceptual question about coding.
- Code Review: You've a bunch of code you want reviewed.

I fail to see the overlap.

Comment: Ok, but do you think the community is going to make the distinction?

Comment: @GertArnold Seems to be working out well so far. Programmers.SE has been around for 13 months, Code Review for 8.

Comment: @GertArnold: Do you have an actual example where this is not the case/a problem?

Comment: @PaddedCell I see a comments like "great question for CodeReview" appearing very often at SO, but I can understand that. This is a question that was duplicated at both sites: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708904/adding-text-to-the-tool-strip-progress-bar.

Comment: @GertArnold: That one belongs on Stack Overflow. A very poor question, though.

Comment: @PaddedCell. Agree, twice. But what if OP's don't get it? I am not pro or contra CR, actually I trust it is a good idea if SE thinks it is. But I'm worried about duplicates and misplaces questions.

Comment: @GertArnold: Since Aeons the community is dealing with OPs which 'just don't get it'...so far we win. Joke aside, downvote and vote-to-close as you deem necessary. Leave a comment explaining why, if people don't get it, we can't help them.

Comment: In my opinion the crucial word in this answer is "bunch".  I would be unhappy if constrained, well-posed questions about, for example, efficiency differences between small functions that do the same thing, had to be taken out of SE.  They have been a big part of SE traditionally, and are often given as part of answers about how to make code serve a particular purpose.  I understand the value of having a separate place for review of large chunks of code, though.