# Burninate-Request: coding-style tag. What is the point of it if we have Code Review?

Tags: discussion, tags, stack-exchange, close-reasons, burninate-request

I am mainly referring to this question:

[How can I make this more Pythonic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180624/how-can-i-make-this-more-pythonic)

Basically someone had a simple if statement asking if he could make it more Pythoinic and it was closed because it was considered "off-topic" How is this off-topic if there is a tag that is meant to address these type of questions?

I looked up what exactly is the main purpose for code review and found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108867/code-review-and-stack-overflow-overlap). Basically what I got from it is that Code Review is made with the intention of larger scale projects as opposed to small snippets.

So can someone clarify for me if this question is really considered off-topic? **What exactly is** [coding-style](/questions/tagged/coding-style) **referring to? Should we just burn it?**

EDIT: I found a question that seems to use coding-style a lot more effectively. Is it these type of questions that SO is trying to target with this tag? Arguably this could be put up for Code Review as well though. The main difference is that he doesn't have code.

[How do I design my class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214727/how-do-i-design-my-class)

Comment: The tag's been around longer than Code Review – its existence does not necessarily mean questions tagged with it automatically become on topic. Topicality can change over time, but the tags will stay.

Comment: I'm not even sure what purpose the tag [tag:coding-style] might realistically *have*; I'd consider it a meta-tag, at best.

Comment: @DavidThomas That is kind of what I was trying to get at. I understand it might be an old tag, but now I feel it just confuses people as to what questions you should be asking on SO.

Comment: Definitely smells like a meta tag.  Shall we make it go away then?  What questions in this tag are worth keeping?

Comment: @Makoto: I can't see how it is a meta tag. It is also good for categorizing and searching.

Comment: Categorizing what?  Why should those questions be categorized?  If you remove the tag from one of those questions, could it stand on its own merits?  That's what it means to have a meta tag.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask, if you only leave one tag in the question, does it still make sense? I think "coding style" has quite an unambiguous meaning and could be used alone. In my view, the issue then becomes, are any questions so tagged on topic here, or should they be at programmers or code review.